# Helper function use in Ruby on Rails (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a helper function that strips all stopwords from the content field of data. I've used the basic scaffolding, like so:

```
rails generate scaffold MyData pageId:integer content:text
```

I've added a private method in the controller as such:

```
  private
  STOP_WORDS = %w{a am an as at be by do go he i if in is it me my no of on or so to un up us we}

  def remove_stop_words(lowercase_string)
    lowercase_string.gsub(/\b(#{STOP_WORDS.join('|')})\b/mi, '')
  end
```

and now I'm wondering, since the controller is

```
  def index
    @tube_data = TubeDatum.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tube_data }
    end
  end
```

and the corresponding view is

```
<% @tube_data.each do |tube_datum| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= tube_datum.pageId %></td>
    <td><%= tube_datum.content %></td>

....
```

how to go about making each tube_data.content stripped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the function in: app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  STOP_WORDS = %w{a am an as at be by do go he i if in is it me my no of on or so to un up us we}

  def remove_stop_words(lowercase_string)
    lowercase_string.gsub(/\b(#{STOP_WORDS.join('|')})\b/mi, '')
  end
```

In the view:

```
<%= remove_stop_words(tube_datum.content) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move that code from your Controller into application_helper.rb in the app/helpers folder and wrap it in a method called stripstopwords.

Then in your view go stripstopwords tube_datum.content